# strongswan: What is the difference between left and leftid?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan

[This tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-ipsec-vpn-with-strongswan-on-debian-ubuntu/) use `left` parameter when setup strongswan, while [this tutorial](https://sysadmins.co.za/setup-a-site-to-site-ipsec-vpn-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu/) also use `leftid` parameter. What is the difference between `left` and `leftid`?

**Update**

I setup strongswan on aws ec2 with the config as following:

```
conn aws-to-corp
        authby=secret
        #left=%any
        left=52.82.6.111
        leftid=52.82.6.111
        leftsubnet=172.30.0.0/20
        right=223.71.239.218
        rightsubnet=192.168.1.0/24
        ike=3des-md5-modp1024!
        esp=3des-md5!
        keyingtries=0
        ikelifetime=1h
        lifetime=8h
        dpddelay=30
        dpdtimeout=120
        dpdaction=restart
        auto=start
```

When I set `left=%any`, strongswan works fine, but when I set `left=52.82.6.111`, there are some error in `/var/log/syslog`:
[image]

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One defines the local IP address(es), `left`, which does not have to be specified unless it should be restricted. The other, `leftid`, the local identity used during authentication, which will default to the local IP address or the subject DN of the local certificate, if one is configured.

Note that the convention is to use `left...` options for local settings and `right...` for those of the remote, but they might get swapped if an IP in `right` is found locally.

Please refer to the man page for ipsec.conf (`man ipsec.conf`) or the [wiki page for the conn section](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Connsection) for details.

---

You can't set `left` to an IP address that's not installed on any local interface. As you can see in the log, the daemon won't be able to send packets from that address. Likewise, inbound request are dropped because the destination address doesn't match the config (the `no IKE config found for ...` message). So either don't configure it (same as setting it to `%any`) or configure a local address from/on which packets can be sent/received (e.g. `172.30.13.1` in your case).

Comment: I have update the question, can you explain why I can't set `left=52.82.6.111`?